# Android 5.1.1 ionic webview connection refused

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm building an app with Ionicframework.  I've tested on emulators and on a couple of devices using older android firmware.

Trying the app on a phone using 5.1.1 I get the following error.

[image]

The following permissions are in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I use the following in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: most probably something is blocking Port 8100 -- have you got a firewall, Antivirus turned on  -- turn them off and try again

Comment: error is on phone, over wifi or 3g

Comment: 192.168.1.4 >> which IP is this?

Comment: I believe it's the ip of the device